# What does this paper means by $S$-homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

So I'm reading https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.04204, and I'm confused about a certain definition:

> **Matrix factorizations.** Let $S$ be a commutative ring and $x$ and element of $S$. A *matrix factorization* $(F,g,\phi,\psi)$ of $x$ is a diagram
>   $$F\stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow} G\stackrel{\psi}{\longrightarrow}F$$
>   in which $F$ and $G$ are finitely generated free $S$-modules, and $\phi$ and $\psi$ are $S$-homomorphisms satisfying
>   $$\psi\circ \phi=x\cdot 1_F$$
>   $$\phi\circ \psi=x\cdot 1_G.$$

How can a $S$-homomorphism from a module to another module be defined? Can you assume that the modules are necessarily $S$?

Comment: I assume by "$S$-homomorphism", they mean a homomorphism of $S$-modules, i.e. an $S$-linear map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here "$S$-homomorphism" means "homomorphism of $S$-modules"; this simply means that $\phi(sa+b)=s\phi(a)+\phi(b)$ for all $s\in S$ and all $a,b\in F$ (and similarly for $\psi$).